# Delete A Row In a Listbox that Gets Data from Access database

Tags: sql, vba, excel, listbox

So right now I have a listbox that gets data from an access database and prints it out like below:
[image]

When the user clicks on "Just Lose It" for example, and then clicks "Remove Song" button, how can I delete that entry from the database and then refresh the list box with the updated table.

I was thinking of creating an SQL DELETE Statement and then use a ADODB.Recordset to run that statement but I'm not sure how to tell the user clicked that entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the form's underlying vba code? It will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: What is the setting on the `MultiSelect` property for that listbox. It affects how to solves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like the following... add unique key if in hidden column

```
sqlStr = "DELETE FROM music WHERE [Title] = '" & music_lb.column(0) & "' AND [Artist] = '" & music_lb.column(1) & "' AND [Album] = '" & music_lb.column(2) &  "';"
```